# Understanding millis() in digitalWrite()

Tags: arduino, milliseconds

I have been doing a lot more Arduino programming, especially going back to things I have done before and getting rid of `delay()` where I can. I [ran across an interesting post](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=449792.0) having the following code to "flash" an LED:

```
digitalWrite(strobe1, (millis() % 1000L) < 500L);
```

I read the math as *(current milliseconds modulo 1000) < 500* and this math seems to "flash" the LED. What I don't quite understand is ***why***? The math doesn't seem to be a test (*result of mod is less than 500*) but does set the pin `HIGH` for whatever is being calculated here.

I have been searching the web to try and understand what is going on here, but cannot find anything explicit. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read the math as (current milliseconds modulo 1000) < 500

Thats correct.

> What I don't quite understand is why? The math doesn't seem to be a test

I don't really understand your statement. `(millis() % 1000L) < 500L` is a test, it tests whether `millis() % 1000L` is less than `500` or not and results in either `true`, which is equivalent to `1` or `false`, which is equivalent to `0`.

So, half of a second, the condition is false -> `0` gets written, and the other half of a second it's true, `1` gets written.

> I guess I am used to seeing the test being more explicit, like if((millis() % 1000L) < 500). So this is a ternary function?

No, not at all a ternary, neither a if. You need to understand what a logical/boolean expression is and results in. Lets break it down a bit:

```
 bool result = (millis() % 1000L) < 500L;
```

It should be clear what this line does: It checks whether the result of `millis() % 1000L` is less than 500 and stores the resulting boolean in `result`. A boolean is nothing more than true or false. A value. A value like `1`, `34561` or `"hello world"`. Of course, you *can* use the value as a conditional in a `if` statement like this:

```
if(result) { /* some code */ } else { /* more code */ }
```

But you don't need to. Because its *just* a value, where `true` is the same as `1` and `false` is the same as `0`, you can pass this boolean which implicitly decays to the corresponding integer (it always was a integer to begin with) to a function which expects a HIGH (`1`)  or a LOW (`0`). You could also think of the `digitalWrite` function as if it would take in a `bool` instead of the logical `1` or `0`, the result would be the same.

Comment: I guess I am used to seeing the test being more explicit, like `if((millis() % 1000L) < 500)`. So this is a ternary function?

Comment: No, not a ternary, I guess you misunderstand what a boolean expression actually is. Let me add a bit of clarification to my question...

Comment: That why we should always strive for more explicit code, i.e. `digitalWrite(strobe1, (millis() % 1000L) < 500L ? HIGH : LOW);` would be much clearer, and would probably optimize out to the exact same code anyway.

Comment: Thank you! I had flashbacks to C programming which I haven't done in a long time.